# Javafx dynamic column amount

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

Say I have a javafx application and I want to display e.g. a list with 15 images in this application. The images should always have the same size so if the user resizes the application, if there is not enough space to show e.g. 3 images next to each other, only 2 should be shown and the others move into a new "row".

Is there any container which applies such a behavior or do I have to implement it on my own?
If so - any general tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a `FlowPane` would suit you just fine. See [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/layout-tutorial/builtin_layouts.htm#sthref21), or the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/FlowPane.html).  You can also consider the `TilePane` described right after the `FlowPane`, if all images are the same size.

Comment: works like a charm but how can I add a scroll bar to the TilePane to "scroll through" all images?

Comment: nvm did it with using "Fit to Height/Width" on a scrollpane thanks!